# on Android configuration changed Application is restarting

Tags: android

I am newbie to android development. I am writing an application and my requirement is when the orientation changes the application does not restart. Below is the sample application which i am testing in the samsung galaxy duos mobile.

I'm using the 4.0.4 Android OS Version, and my application is developed under API level 8.

I tried with the following methods:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Please Help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is starting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }   
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
     if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main );
    } 
    }


}
```

### and my mainfest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.orientationtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

since `Android 3.0+` if you want the system managing your change of orientation you should add also `screenSize` .

You should set in your manifest as `targetSdkVersion` a version `>= 3.0` . For instance

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: I am getting the Error as follows: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|
 keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize').

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

In your manifest file

It works for me

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.stack.MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, As you mention we already tried with that still the application is restarting

Comment: You should work with the changes as I shown and post. May be you misspelled.

Comment: '<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>'

Comment: look at my answer carefully and try accordingly. It works for me. orientation|keyboardHidden

Comment: can you send me the sample application to my email: ntlabs.damodaram@gmail.com @ling.s

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".YourMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 ....
 </application>
```

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|
 keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize').

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

in the activity declaration at the manifest.

Comment: I am developing in the eclipse IDE and when i add screenSize in the manifest and save i am getting the error as follows: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|
 keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize').

Comment: on which sdk are you working?

i am working on 
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />